# A strange issue in the commad of SetName()

Tags: dm-script

I found a strange issue while using the SetName in DM scripting. The example code is as follows. Somehow the output image cannot be properly renamed. One possible solution is that I use "=" instead of ":=" to assign my processed image. Howeve, all the tags will be lost.

Could anyone know the reason?

Thanks in advance

```
image IMG := RealImage("",4,1024,1024,11)

number sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ

IMG.Get3DSize(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ)

number sizeZ1 = (sizeZ+1)/2
image subIMG := IMG.Slice3(0,0,0,0,sizeX,1,1,sizeY,1,2,sizeZ1,2)

subIMG.SetName("Sub-volume of a Stack")
subIMG.ShowImage()
```

Comment: When you report some *specific* behavior, please always make sure to also state which version of DigitalMicrograph you are running. Due to *bugs* or changes between versions, it might very well be that the same script code leads to different results on different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Nothing *strange* here, just a logical consequence of using the := operator

When you use `:=` to assing to an image variable, you are just giving a reference to a memory location.
Hence, using

`image subIMG := IMG.Slice3(0,0,0,0,sizeX,1,1,sizeY,1,2,sizeZ1,2)`

does not at all create an image, but only points (in a clever way) to the same memory where `IMG` keeps its data. Essentially, you now have two variables pointing to the same memory. You can see this by doing

```
Image full := RealImage("Full image",4, 200, 200 )
full = icol
full.ShowImage()

Image sub := full.Slice2(50,50,0, 0,20,3, 1,20,3 )
sub = sub *-1
```

and noticing that the values of `full` have changed!

Because 'subIMG' is not really an image on its own, the command to set it's name is ignored. (Note, that using `ShowImage` doesn't change this. One can create multiple displays onto the *identical* data - sometimes quite useful, actually.)

Now if you *want* `subIMG` to be it's own image, then you actually need to copy the (subsampled) data to a new memory location. As you suggested, using `=` would perform this automatically, but only for the *values* not for any *meta data*.
To copy *values and meta data* from an image, you need to use the command `ImageClone`. So in your script above, what you want to do is:

```
image IMG := RealImage("",4,1024,1024,11)

number sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ

IMG.Get3DSize(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ)

number sizeZ1 = (sizeZ+1)/2
image subIMG := IMG.Slice3(0,0,0,0,sizeX,1,1,sizeY,1,2,sizeZ1,2).ImageClone()

subIMG.SetName("Sub-volume of a Stack")
subIMG.ShowImage()
```